# Display my map legend

Tags: google-maps

I've embeded a google my maps map on a website. I would like to have the legend menu (on the left) already opened when the iframe is loaded. Is there a parameter that I can send along?

Comment: I have the same issue. Would love to be able to supply a parameter to auto display the "My Maps" legend when the page is first loaded. Interestingly, it does this when you click the expansion icon and view the map full screen.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there isn't any optional parameter that would allow this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide